# Where do I punctuate in this?

Tags: punctuation

> I may have to stop going here, for school, and resume after, if you permit me to.

Where do I place punctuation marks, commas, here?

Answer (score 3):

The original sentence sounds a little stilted with that many commas. In terms of punctuation in this case, less is more. Also, I would recommend writing it as: *I may have to stop going to school here (for now) and resume afterwards, if you will permit me.* Additional note: without any context, it's unknown after what exactly you will be resuming school, so make sure that's clear. However, if there isn't a particular event after which you will be resuming school, it's perfect fine to omit *after* since that is implied with *resume*.

Answer (score 1):

In general, do not place a comma in the middle of a sentence unless it is necessary. Comma overuse is one of the most common mistakes in written English.

The only place in that sentence that needs a comma is before "if you permit me to." This is an independent clause, meaning it could stand alone as a sentence. Independent clauses are almost always preceded by a comma when they come later on in a sentence.

I would punctuate the sentence like this: "I may have to stop going here for school and resume after, if you permit me to."